# React component uncaught type error: TypeError: books.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a spring backend that is serving my react front end, I am trying to generate a list of all books in storage but I get this error at runtime `Uncaught TypeError: books is undefined ListBookComponent ListBookComponent.jsx:37`

TypeError: books.map is not a function

my ListBookComponent.jsx

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { listBooks } from '../services/BookService'

const ListBookComponent = () => {

    const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
     
    
    useEffect(() => {
        listBooks().then((response) => {
            setBooks(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })


    }, [])
   


    

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h1 className='text-center'>List of Books</h1>
      <table className='table table-striped table-bordered'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Language</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {
              ** 37 **books.map(book =>
                    <tr key={book.id}>
                        <td>{book.id}</td>
                        <td>{book.name}</td>
                        <td>{book.language}</td>

                    </tr>)
            }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ListBookComponent
```

I've highlighted line 37  where the error occurs

the json response from my api

```
{"status":"Success","results":[{"id":1,"name":"Tenzi Za Rohoni","language":"Kiswahili"}]}
```

bookservice.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const REST_API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/books';

export const listBooks = () => axios.get(REST_API_BASE_URL);
```

I've tried changing the json response format but i didn't work. While debugging I came across
where the breakpoint is

```
  if (hasUncaughtError) {
    hasUncaughtError = false;
    var error$1 = firstUncaughtError;
    firstUncaughtError = null;
    throw error$1;
  } // If the passive effects are the result of a discrete render, flush them
  // synchronously at the end of the current task so that the result is
  // immediately observable. Otherwise, we assume that they are not
  // order-dependent and do not need to be observed by external systems, so we
  // can wait until after paint.
  // TODO: We can optimize this by not scheduling the callback earlier. Since we
  // currently schedule the callback in multiple places, will wait until those
  // are consolidated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your response also contains status property and not only array of books so you should save the data in react state in the following way

```
setBooks(response.data?.results || []);
```

Comment: So if I took out the status property so that my reponse only contained an array of books  would setBooks(response.data) work or what am I missing

Comment: @EmmanuelKiprono its fine as well